# jQuery - Selecting element after current position

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to do is select the next element below where I am on the page. I want to do this to create a "View next post" function. So, if I am past the beginning of post 2, then I want the function to take me to post 3. Conventional jQuery will ask me which child to use of the parents and by default use the first instance, but I want to select the next post below the top of the screen.

So far I am able to grab the current position of the page using:

```
var curPos = $('html').offset();
var Posi = String(curPos.top).replace(/-/g, "");
```

But I'm not sure how to filter a function to only select elements below that position.

Help?

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

Comment: That certainly helps, but I need to be able to select elements that are visible rather than just test if they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a great time to extend the selector:

```
 $.extend($.expr[':'], {
      pos: function(a,i,m){
          if(!m[3]){return false;}
          // whatever logic you need to determine 
          // if element is below document offset
          // goes here, simply make this function return true or false
          return $(a).offset().top >= parseFloat(m[3]);
      }
 });
```

now you should be able to do something like this:

```
 $('.className:pos('+curPos+')').foo();
```

---

Or you can use `.filter` which will do something similar

```
 $('.className').filter(function(){
      // whatever logic you need to determine 
      // if element is below document offset
      // goes here, simply make this function return true or false
      return $(this).offset().top >= curPos;
 }).foo();
```

The difference is filter occurs only once, while extending the selector is fully reusable.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've already figured it out but this is great. I'll use it later.